# Can I enter the UK without my husband if we said we'd travel together in our visa application?

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas

My husband and I along with my kids will be traveling to London to attend a wedding ceremony. We will travel on different dates 10 days apart. So do we need to mention our traveling dates different on visa application? Also if we fill same dates on our application, Am I possibly be asked by the immigration office why am I entering London with out him?

Comment: Being completely truthful in your application and statements is always the best course of action. Why would you want to hide this aspect of your travel? Is there something your husband will be doing in that 10 day period that's embarrassing or improper? And if your record shows you're married and going with your children to a wedding, it'd be perfectly normal to be asked "And your husband...where's he?"

Comment: Anyone in the UK (not just an immigration officer) might wonder *why* you are travelling "to attend a wedding" and arriving 10 days beforehand. But so long as you have a credible story about what you are going to do for those 10 days, and enough money to support yourself while doing it, that is not a reason to refuse you entry. (I know that in some cultures wedding ceremonies and celebrations extend over several days, but in the UK they usually do not.)

Comment: My sister in law lives there with her family, my kids are having long spring break so I wanna spend the break with kids in London for quiet long on the contrary my husband is having just a week break to attend a ceremony . I am quiet sure this wouldn’t be the reason of refusal as i have traveled before london in past. What i was confused about the dates mentioning in the application as I thought i may b asked about my husband.

Answer (score 21):

> Do we need to mention our traveling dates different on visa application?

Of course.  Always tell the truth.

> Also if we fill same dates on our application, Am I possibly be asked by the immigration office why am I entering London with out him?

Of course.  Anything that the immigration officer observes that is inconsistent with the visa application is a possible cause for concern, and the officer will almost certainly ask about it.  That is the principal reason why you should tell the truth in the application.

In the UK immigration system, the consequences of not telling the truth are quite severe.  On the other hand, traveling to the UK separately from your spouse has no negative consequences by itself.  So *tell the truth.*

Comment: @mayasheikh Honestly is the best policy. That a spouse may travel later due to business reasons would be considered a legitimate reason. Keep things as simple and truthful as possible.